# ¿Cómo puedo dar formato de subrayado, tachado... a un string en c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy realizando una aplicación, creando un FontDialog ajustado a ciertas necesidades. Estoy intentando dar formato a un label, dependiendo de si encuentra o no el check clicado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que al clicar en "Subrayado" o "Tachado", el texto adquiera ese formato (subrayado, tachado). Mi código es el siguiente:

```
private void chkTachado_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chkTachado.Checked)
            {
                
                chkTachado.Text = chkTachado.Text.
            }
        }
```

¿Cómo podría hacerse? En la documentación, se habla de una clase TextDecorations, pero no consigo implementarla. Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Es WinForms o WPF?

Comment: Hola Nicolás. En winforms

Comment: Copia y pega el código donde intentas implementar la clase `TextDecorations`

Comment: Hola @JakintsuIheslari, puedes decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles y marcar como aceptada la q mas te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este algoritmo tiene cierta complejidad ya que el **Label** puede tener como estilo: **Tachado, Subrayado, Ambos o Ninguno**, **son cuatro combinaciones posibles**, por ejemplo si marcaras tachado solamente el texto tendrá el estilo tachado, pero si marcas ambos **CheckBox** el texto deberá tener ambos estilos a la vez. Este código soluciona ese problema:

```
if (checkTachado.Checked)
{
   label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Strikeout | label1.Font.Style);
}
else
{
   if (checkSubrayado.Checked)
   {
      label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
   }
   else
   {
      label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
   }
}
```

En este código se comprueba si el **CheckBox** para el **estilo tachado** está activo o se marcó, de estarlo se le da al **Label** el **estilo tachado** concatenado al estilo previo que ya tenía:

```
FontStyle.Strikeout | label1.Font.Style
```

Esta linea asegura eso, es decir combina el **estilo tachado** con cualquier estilo que ya tenga el **Label**.

Si **checkTachado** no está marcado o se desmarca entonces se pregunta si **checkSubrayado** está marcado, de estarlo se le da al **Label** solamente el **estilo subrayado**, de no estarlo se le da un **estilo normal**, es decir **ni marcado ni subrayado**.

El código del **estilo subrayado** sería:

```
if (checkSubrayado.Checked)
{
   label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Underline | label1.Font.Style);
}
else
{
   if (checkTachado.Checked)
   {
      label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Strikeout);                  
   }
   else
   {
      label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
   }
}
```

Comment: Me ha resultado muy útil. Gracias por tu respuesta. Me ha funcionado, y sigo adelante con mi aplicación, con futuros nuevos retos

Comment: @JakintsuIheslari, que bueno q te sirvió, podrías por favor marcar la respuesta como aceptada y si lo deseas también darle un voto, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que subrayar el control no el string, en este caso el Label

```
private void chkTachado_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkTachado.Checked)
        {
            
            chkTachado.Font = new Font(FontStyle.Underline);.
        }
    }
```